# Strange behaviour of GLSL application on Mac OS X using XCode

Tags: xcode, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to set up a working OpenGL/GLUT/GLSL example in XCode on Mac OS X.

This is what I've done so far:

1. Create a new terminal project
2. Link Cocoa.framework, OpenGL.framework and GLUT.framework in target build phases
3. Write a simple OpenGL/glut/glsl example program
4. Add a "Copy files" Build Phase to the target executable, set the destination to Executables and added the shader source files to that build phase
5. Run the program.

The code works totally fine on another unix machine, and it's been written for Mac aswell by my class instructor so there should be no problems with the code. I'm thinking there's an error in my setup of the project.

The strange behavior that I'm having problems with is:
When I resize the glut window the image shown is destroyed and only sometimes the proper image shows up. I can post image links upon request.

The shader source files are found. It's just the strange graphic behavior I'm concerned about.

My shader code:
Vertex shader:

```
#version 150
in  vec3 in_Position;
void main(void)
{
gl_Position = vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 150
out vec4 out_Color;
void main(void)
{
out_Color = vec4(1.0);
}
```

Comment: For some small window size I can hint the image of the uTorrent icon which is on the right of my Mac tab of icons at the bottom of my screen. Does it access the video memory incorrectly?

Comment: Perhaps you're not calling `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` or `glutPostRedisplay`? You can also check simple shaders with [Shader Builder](https://developer.apple.com/downloads) (Graphics Tools for Xcode).

Comment: It sounds like it's displaying uninitialized video memory, and the last thing that was in that memory was your Dock. As Brett says, you probably need to clear some things.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case you need to set up a GLUT *reshape* callback, which is called when a window.  In that callback, you usually update a few things:

- the viewport
- your projection transformation (if you're using one)

A common simple implementation of a GLUT reshape function is:

```
void
reshape( int width, int height )
{
    glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );
    // Update projection transform, usually including new window
    //   aspect ratio: width / height
}
```

You would register `reshape` like your other GLUT callbacks by calling `glutReshapeFunc`